# How to detect change of dynamic value

Tags: dynamic, lua

i need to detect if value is changing

```
local angles = render.get_camera_angles()
function blur()
    if changing(angles) == false then return end

    render.blur(screen)
end
```

screen blur if angles changing

Comment: It depends on what ```render.get_camera_angles()``` will return - Is it only a number? Or is it a table? If it is only a number than you can do: ```if render.get_camera_angles() == angles then return end```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.

```
values = {}
cdcheck = 0
changing = function(name, delay, value)
    cdcheck = cdcheck + 1
    if cdcheck > delay then
        values[name] = value
        cdcheck = 0
    end
    if values[name] ~= value then return true end
    return false
end
register_callback('ingame', function()
    if changing('cam_angles_x', 50, render.get_camera_angles().x) then
        -- blur here
    end
end)
```